# After answering a question I received multiple down votes on other answers as well

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm a little shaky while writing this one. I answered this question:

[Beginner javascript, why is this event not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19772138/1456376)

I think with a valid answer to push the OP - who is a beginner - into the right direction. The answer received a negative vote. OK, happens.

A minute later I received a negative vote for no reason on another answer. Then suddenly it's getting upvotes again. Then more downvotes on other answers appear - also on old ones. Still while I'm writing here on meta. :-/

What's going on here? Is someone on a downvoting spree? I was so happy coming near the 10k and now this. It seems that lately everything it's getting a little rough here. Even if you give little hints and try to help somebody. I'm just really sad at this moment. Maybe somebody with enough reputation can take a look at it? I may simply remove all my downvoted answers.

*As a note*: I'm thinking since nearly 30 minutes to press "Post your question" or not. If the answer to this is "You have to live with it", please simply leave a comment and I will remove this question later.

Comment: *serial voting* gets reversed every 24 hours.

Comment: Is this *serial voting* already?

Comment: @juergend Thanks for adding the link as well.

Comment: @juergend what is the limit for serial voting, I mean how many votes?, if that votes were not reached, then what is the solution ?

Comment: The algorithm is secret to prevent flying under the radar. If it does not get reversed after a day you can flag for moderator attention and explain the matter.

Comment: @insertusernamehere It may be serial voting, and it may not.  You'll find out in a day based on whether or not its reversed.

Comment: @juergend where to flag for moderator attention, you mean any of the downvoted post

Comment: @bala Yep, that will do.